# I am fixing first 2 columns of table but design is not proper

Tags: html, css

I have fixed first 2 columns of table but it is showing one extra row in table header.

```css
.headcol {
  position:absolute; 
  width:7em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 0px;
}
.headcol2 {
  position:absolute; 
  width:15em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-le
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"  style="margin-left: 227px;display: block;height:400px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="headcol">Membership No</th>
      <th class="headcol2" rowspan="2">Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Sallery No</th>
      <th rowspan="2">MBS</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Shares</th>
      <th rowspan="2">CD</th>
      <th rowspan="2">RD</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciak</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciah</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciag</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
</table>
```

In this it has fixed first 2 columns but the first interest is show on the empty row.Please help.You can see my design at below :

https://jsfiddle.net/rahulpamnani/nnukubyu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `position: absolute`
like so:

```css
.headcol {
  width:7em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 0px;
}
.headcol2 {
  width:15em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-le
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"  style="margin-left: 227px;display: block;height:400px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="headcol">Membership No</th>
      <th class="headcol2" rowspan="2">Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Sallery No</th>
      <th rowspan="2">MBS</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Shares</th>
      <th rowspan="2">CD</th>
      <th rowspan="2">RD</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciak</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciah</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciag</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
</table>
```

---

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove `absolute position` so that the second heading does not overlap

If this is what you wanted and i understood the question

```css
.headcol {
  
  width:7em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 0px;
}
.headcol2 {
   
  width:15em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"  style="margin-left: 227px;display: block;height:400px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="headcol">Membership No</th>
      <th class="headcol2" rowspan="2">Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Sallery No</th>
      <th rowspan="2">MBS</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Shares</th>
      <th rowspan="2">CD</th>
      <th rowspan="2">RD</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciak</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciah</th>
      <th colspan="2">speciag</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: this is what is want but i want to fix first 2 columns of the table because it has horizontal scroll property.Jones Joseph

Comment: what do you mean by horizontal scroll? On my browser it looks ok

Comment: But when anyone performs horizontal scroll the first two columns of the table will be fixed to left.That's why i set position of first 2 columns of the table absolute.@SandrinaPereira

Answer (score 0):

```
 .headcol 
  {
  position:absolute; 
  width:7em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 0px;
  }
  .headcol2 
 {
  position:absolute; 
  width:15em; 
  top:auto;
  left: 100px;
 }
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-le
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"  style="margin-left: 227px;display: block;height:400px;">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th rowspan="2" class="headcol">Membership No</th>
     <th class="headcol2" rowspan="2">Name</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Sallery No</th>
     <th rowspan="2">MBS</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Shares</th>
     <th rowspan="2">CD</th>
     <th rowspan="2">RD</th>
     <th colspan="2">speciak</th>
     <th colspan="2">speciah</th>
     <th colspan="2">speciag</th>
     <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Principal</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
   </tr>
```

Just Create an extra column in second row.I want first 2 columns of table to fixed when any scroll the table horizontally.